# Rexx sleep command

Tags: rexx, tso

I want to make the CPU go from 0% utilization back to 100% every 10 seconds.
Kind of like waves if that makes sense.
I was wondering if anybody could help me since I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You're expected to make an effort and show some code.

Comment: Why? I mean, there's no legitimate use for this so perhaps this is the wrong question and the operating system, will actively prevent you from doing this. Tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `Address TSO "OPSWAIT 10"` and some kind of busy loop.

Comment: You've no chance of getting the CPU to hit 100% through REXX. also OPSWAIT is specific to Ops/MVS which may not be installed.

Comment: @SteveIves Indeed, 100% load would be a bug in the scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

OPSWAIT looks like an OPS/MVS command which the OP may not have.

Here is a general routine that you can model that uses the OMVS (aka USS) sleep function:

```
/* rexx */                                 
/* call USS sleep routine */               
parse arg sleep_sec .                      
say time()                                 
address 'SYSCALL' 'SLEEP ('sleep_sec')'    
say time()                                 
return 0
```